# regular expression match a string 'xxx(yyy) (zzz(qqq))' or 'xxx(yyy)'

Tags: python, regex

I want to match string below,

```
str1: xxx(yyy) (zzz(qqq))
str2: xxx(yyy)
```

I write a regular expression  which can only match str1:

```
>>> s = re.compile(r'([^\(]+)\((.+)\)\s*\(([^\(]+)\((.+)\)\)')
>>> m = s.match('xxx(yyy) (zzz(qqq))')
>>> for i in m.groups(): print i
...
xxx
yyy
zzz
qqq
>>> m = s.match('xxx(yyy)')
>>> for i in m.groups(): print i
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It also fails here for the first case.

Comment: @Felix Yan it works, please copy the str1, the brackets in str1 is chinese

Comment: it yields the same error here: https://paste.xinu.at/v9Pd

Comment: @Felix Yan that is realy strange, my local environment is fine.Can you test in local?

Comment: Well, I am testing it in local environment. And even setting locale to Chinese doesn't help.

Comment: @Felix Yan Maybe some environment different? I have change example to english, please test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` means that you can't apply the `groups` method to nothing.

`match` returns None if the string does not match the pattern

Your regex is incorrect, the third and fourth group may not exist. It's best to look for any strings within parenthesis or not.

Also `match` only looks for the matching pattern at beginning of the line.
You could use `findall` but it would return a list, so `finditer` seems more appropriate

This is the corrected regex : `s = re.compile(r'(?:\(?([^\(\)]+)\(?([^\(\)]+)\)\)?\s*)')`

However, using finditer you just need to look for a simpler pattern. So the regex below is different:

```
import re

s=re.compile(r'\(?([^\s\(\)]+)\)?')


string1='aa (bbbb) (cc (dddd) )'
string2='aa (bbbb) '


for string in [string1,string2]:
    print string
    m = s.finditer(string)
    for i in m: print i.group(1)
```